# collecting infos about SAP ERP

Tags: sap-erp, s4hana

I want to start courses on SAP ERP but I have no idea what is it about or where should I start.

Of course I did search online and got an overview but the number of courses in SAP website are just a lot!

I would be very happy if someone can tell me, based on my educational background, which course shroud I take to guarantee my future job.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Guru99’s [‘What is SAP?’](https://www.guru99.com/what-is-sap.html) guide will give you a good introduction to SAP, as well as detailing the steps to getting certified, and getting employed as an SAP consultant. This makes it a great introduction to the field, with both theoretical background and practical steps.

In terms of advising on specific courses, this would very much depend on you deciding the specific area of SAP you'd like to go into. As this is something you’re new to, I hope the following helps provide you with the context you need to make a decision about which area of SAP work might be right for you.

Assuming you do not have access to the SAP Learning Hub, one of the best resources to learn about SAP is [OpenSAP](https://open.sap.com/courses). It has a huge back catalogue covering all technical and functional areas of SAP. Anybody can sign up to any of their courses and certificates as evidence of your learning are available. If the course is currently being run, you can get a certificate for free, otherwise you’ll have to pay a small fee for a certificate. They recently ran a course called [‘Two-Tier ERP with SAP S/4HANA Cloud’](https://open.sap.com/courses/s4h9), looking at explaining the entire system for SAP ERP, which might be of interest to you. This course should provide an overview, as well as familiarising you with the most up to date technologies used.

If you're looking to work on SAP ERP on a technical level, an essential skill will be ABAP programming. The ['SAP ABAP Programming For Beginners' course on Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/sap-abap-programming-for-beginners/) provides a comprehensive introduction to the language, and how it is used in SAP.

In addition to looking at courses, I’d recommend taking advantage of the wealth of resources available on SAP’s websites. SAP provides [roadmaps](https://www.sap.com/uk/products/roadmaps.html) for its products, which will give you a sense of how to practically apply the knowledge you learn on your courses. I’d also recommend looking through the [SAP Community Network](https://www.sap.com/uk/community.html), which, like Stack Overflow, has a wiki, a Q&A platform, and a wealth of blog posts detailing various SAP concepts.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
That was really thorough and helpful!